# How to make sql query on table name with space separated in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgres database and it has table with name say 'System Tenant'. Now I want to make query on it, I do -

```
select * from "System Tenant";
```

but it results into error -

```
ERROR:  relation "System Tenant" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "System Tenant"
                       ^
```

Could you please suggest how I can resolve it?

Comment: Try using escape sequence : select * from "System\ Tenant"

Comment: This still did not work.

Comment: What name exactly does `\d` show you in `psql` (or `select tablename from pg_tables where lower(tablename) like 'system%'`)? I guess it might be `"system tenant"` or `"SYSTEM TENANT"` or something similar - as soon as you use double quotes the name is case sensitive.

Comment: @user5542464: the backslash is not an "escape character" in SQL strings

Answer (score 3):

lets say:

```
so=# create schema t;
CREATE SCHEMA
so=# create table t."Bad Name"();
CREATE TABLE
so=# create table "b@d Name"();
CREATE TABLE
```

now find all:

```
so=# select oid::regclass from pg_class where relname ilike '% name%';
     oid
--------------
 t."Bad Name"
 "b@d Name"
(2 rows)
```

and use exactly as it is listed:

```
so=# select * from t."Bad Name";
--
(0 rows)
```

or

```
so=# select * from "b@d Name";
--
(0 rows)
```